# Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' using Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, attributeerror

When I try to run my automation python script for a different browsers through the terminal window by using the command:

```
pytest -s -v testcase/test_login --browser Chrome
```

where test_login the python main file getting the Attribute error.

The below code is for test_login:

```
from self import self
from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage
from utilities.readProperties import ReadConfig
from utilities.customLogger import LogGen


class Test_001_Login:
    baseURL = ReadConfig.getApplicationURL()
    username = ReadConfig.getUseremail()
    password = ReadConfig.getPassword()
    logger = LogGen.loggen()

def test_login(self, setup):
    self.driver = setup
    self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
    self.logger.info("URL iS loaded successfully")
    self.driver.maximize_window()

    self.lp = LoginPage(self.driver)

    self.lp.setUserName(self.username)
    self.logger.info("username   entered successfully")
    self.lp.setPassword(self.password)
    self.logger.info("password   entered successfully")
    self.lp.clickLogin()
    self.logger.info("clicked on login button")
    self.driver.close()
```

> Below code is conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def setup(browser):


if browser == 'Chrome':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver1\chromedriver.exe")


elif browser == 'firfox':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver1\chromedriver.exe")

elif browser == 'edge':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver1\chromedriver.exe")

    return driver


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")


@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")
```

Answer (score 0):

The CLI argument is errorprone. You need to replace `test_logn` with the eact name of the test class i.e. *`test_login`*, effectively:

```
pytest -s -v testcase/test_login --browser Chrome
```

Furhter, `setup()` is a function, not an object. Update `def test_login()` as follows:

```
def test_login(self, browser):
    setup(browser)
    self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
```

Comment: Changed the method name to test_login. After updating ur changes getting error.* Fixture "setup" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.*

Comment: Pass `browser` as an argument. Updated the code.

Comment: Where should i need to pass is that in conftest.py or test_login.py @undetected Selenium